# Format decimal places to local numeric format

Tags: excel, vba

How do I convert to my local numeric format?

```
Sub test()
    MsgBox Application.DecimalSeparator
    MsgBox Format("25234,32", "#,0#")
    MsgBox Format("25234,32", "#.0#")
End Sub
```

```
Msgbox prints:  
First : ","  
Second: 252.3432  
Third : 25234,32
```

Correct should be 25234,32 for my local settings.

Is it normal that `Format` does not display the same as `.NumberFormatLocal`?

In my program I have text variable with numberformat that's used on `.NumberFormatLocal` so I can't use it on `Format` unless I switch "**.**" and "**,**".

Comment: VBA typically operates on US locale

Comment: It's not very tidy but you can use a cell to translate: `Range("A1").NumberFormatLocal = Local_Format_Name:
English_Format_Name = Range("A1").NumberFormat`

Comment: I see what you mean. I'll try that. I hope it doesn't affect performance. Also looking for an option without accessing cell properties...